# Как согласовать сказуемое при союзе «или»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, однородные-члены, или

*Дождь или снег **обрушился** на город.*
В этом предложении верно ли согласование в единственном числе?

Comment: Замените снег на пургу и получите "пургу". Поэтому неверно. Но множественное число тоже звучит бредово. Это неразрешимая проблема кривого русского языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что рекомендует Розенталь.

> Если между однородными подлежащими стоят разделительные союзы, то возможна двоякая форма согласования:
> **1)** сказуемое ставится в единственном числе, если не возникает необходимость согласования в роде или если подлежащие относятся к одному грамматическому роду, например: ***В нем слышится** то Дант, то Шекспир* (Гончаров); *Пережитый **страх** или мгновенный **испуг** уже через минуту **кажется** и смешным, и странным, и непонятным* (Фурманов); *Не то **туман**, не то **дым окутывал** всю рощу* (Пришвин)...

Наши однородные подлежащие (*дождь, снег*) относятся к одному роду — мужскому, поэтому  выбор единственного числа сказуемого (*обрушился*) является правильным.

Я купил для них обоих, для Бибигона и его сестры, чудесные книжки с картинками, и когда **идёт дождь или снег**, оба читают их целыми днями... [К. И. Чуковский. Приключения Бибигона [прозаические фрагменты] (1945)]

И так продолжалось много дней, похожих один на другой, хотя временами было солнечно, а то **шел дождь или снег**, но однажды она проснулась раньше будильника и, босая, подошла к окну... [Ю. В. Трифонов. Другая жизнь (1975)]

Смутный гул наполнил в это время всю комнату, словно бы по листьям высоких деревьев **приближался** к нам **ветер или дождь**. [В. Я. Брюсов. Огненный ангел (1908)]

Ведь могут быть случаи, когда **остров или материк** постепенно или сразу, но лишь частично **покрывается** наступающим океаном. [Григорий Адамов. Тайна двух океанов (1939)]

[Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-190-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-odnorodnymi-podlezhashchimi)

Comment: А если разные род?

Comment: 1. Правильно: *А если разный род?* 2. Я ведь предоставила Вам, *flossyU*, полную ссылку в ответе: 2) сказуемое ставится во **множественном** числе, если возникает необходимость согласования в роде и подлежащие принадлежат к разному грамматическому роду, например: *…Ни **одно государство или группа государств не должны** получить военное преимущество; **Действие или признак** субъекта (подлежащего) **выражены** сказуемым; **Статья** в целом **или отрывок** из нее **представили** бы интерес для читателей сборника.*

Comment: Да, вижу. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В отличие от сочинительного союза **и** — *дождь и снег обрушились* — разделительный **или** (что ясно из контекста) допускает согласование глагола только с одним существительным.

Comment: Тоже так считаю, но вот пример из словаря (определение слова "выражение"): *Фраза или сочетание слов, часто употребляющиеся в речи.* Почему там так?

Comment: @oleedd В этом предложении речь ведь идет о согласовании *определения*, а не сказуемого (§195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах). 2.  Определение ставится в форме множественного числа...  если определение постпозитивно (даже при наличии разделительного союза между определяемыми словами), например: *Мелкие повреждения кожи смазываются **настойкой** йода или бриллиантовой **зеленью, предохраняющими** от гнойничковых заболеваний.* (http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm)